# Make edges round

Tags: mesh

[image: Example]

How can I round the mesh you can see above or make it more realistic?

Thanks in advance Max.

Comment: One approach: add a subsurface modifier and bevel the edges you don't want to be rounded.

Answer (score 1):

I think u should use *Bevel* modifier in the *Properties* panel

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)